# (React) Use arrow function to handle onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, state

I am pretty new to React. On the internet I often see code where every onChange event (for example from an input field) has its own function and in the constructor there is that bind method called. Couldn't I just use an arrow function for the event to update the state?
Just like

```
onChange={(e) => this.setState({text: e.target.value})}
```

Comment: Yes, using an arrow function works too. Not really sure what else to add...

Comment: Arrow function is used here to solve context issue with the keyword `this` , the scope of `this` will not change in Arrow functions as it refers to the current object it is reffered to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to create arrow function as method, because if we use like `onChange={(e) => this.setState({text: e.target.value})}` we create new instances each time when render method is triggered, so it may affect performance

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  handleChange = (e) => e.preventDefault()
  
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <MyInput
          onChange={ this.handleChange }
        />
      </>  
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using an arrow function gives you additional benefits.

like :

- You don't need to bind it. you can directly use it.

A normal function can not use without binding. To use the normal function first you need to bind that function, but an arrow function you can use directly.